# How many years did Yocheved live?

Tags: midrash, yetziat-mitzrayim, yocheved, serah

**Seder Olam Rabbah 9 - **"Serah bat Asher was among those who came to Egypt and those who left it. [She was] from those who came to Egypt, as it is written, "And Serah their sister" (Genesis 46:17), and [she was] from those who came to the Land [of Israel], as it says, "And there was the daughter of Asher, Serah" (Numbers 26:46). And Yokheved was among those who came to Egypt and those who left it. [She was] from those who came to Egypt, as it is written, "And the name of the wife of Amram was Yokheved, daughter of Levi etc."(ibid. 26:59)."

How many years did Yocheved and Serah live?

Comment: According to this midrash, at least 250 years (if you assume that Yocheved, like Serah, not only left Egypt but also made it to Israel). But see Ibn Ezra to Bereishit 46:27

Comment: According to [Kalla Rabbati](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Kallah_Rabbati.3.25?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), Seraḥ never died, and [Sefer HaYashar, Vayigash](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar_(midrash)%2C_Book_of_Genesis%2C_Vayigash.9?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says similarly: ויברך יעקב את שרח בדברה הדברים האלה לפניו ויאמר אליה, בתי אל ימשול מות בך עד עולם כי החיית את רוחי.